# CoffeeScript and jQuery.post() success: callback

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I have the following script:

```
$ ->
    $('#new_event').submit ->
        $.post(
            $(this).attr('action')
            $(this).serialize()
            success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
                processData(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        )
        return false

processData = (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
    alert(data)
```

and so far I can't for the life of me debug this. It renders as:

```
(function() {
  var processData;
  $(function() {
    return $('#new_event').submit(function() {
      $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), {
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
          return processData(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
        }
      });
      return false;
    });
  });
  processData = function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    return alert(data); //BREAKPOINT HERE
  };
}).call(this);
```

which looks okay to me. If I put the breakpoint on `alert` it never stops there. My javascript knowledge is pretty limited so I'm obviously missing something here. Would love to know what's happening.

Thanks,
Dany.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think your CoffeeScript is okay but your `$.post` arguments are wrong. From the [fine manual](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/):

> `jQuery.post( url [, data] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)] [, dataType] )`

So you don't use the `success: fn(...)` arguments with `$.post`, you just give it a function:

```
$ ->
    $('#new_event').submit ->
        $.post(
            $(this).attr('action')
            $(this).serialize()
            (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
                processData(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        )
        false

processData = (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
    alert(data)
```

or even:

```
$ ->
    $('#new_event').submit ->
        $.post(
            $(this).attr('action')
            $(this).serialize()
            processData
        )
        false

processData = (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
    alert(data)
```

or:

```
$ ->
    $('#new_event').submit ->
        $.post(
            $(this).attr('action')
            $(this).serialize()
            (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
                alert(data)
        )
        false
```

if you don't mind the extra indentation and don't need `processData` elsewhere.

Comment: @muistooshort thank you - this is helpful - if I am receiving JSON back from the server which is a collection of recrds e.g. "@users" - how would i deal with that in call back function. Do I have to use something like:      $.each(data,processData(user)  ->                 and then the code . any advice much appreciated.

Comment: @BKSpurgeon I'm a little unclear on exactly what your situation is, have you asked a question that contains more details?

Comment: @muistooshort hey thanks, basically i want to know how to iterate through a collection of records within the coffeescript using the JSON data that is returned from the server.

Comment: @BKSpurgeon Wouldn't `data` be an array in that case? Then wouldn't you loop over it like any other array?